# Where to use decimal.ROUND_05UP in Python?

Tags: python, numbers, decimal, rounding

The `decimal` module in Python provides this option for rounding a `Decimal`:

```
ROUND_05UP
```

What are some practical uses for this type of rounding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IEEE Decimal Arithmetic](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/damodel.html) spec has this to say about it:

> The rounding mode *round-05up* permits arithmetic at shorter lengths to be emulated in a fixed-precision environment without double rounding. For example, a multiplication at a precision of 9 can be effected by carrying out the multiplication at (say) 16 digits using *round-05up* and then rounding to the required length using the desired rounding algorithm.

In other words, if we round to one precision using `ROUND_05UP` and then round to a shorter precision using some other rounding mode, the result will be the same as if we had directly rounded to the shorter precision.